# Flutter How do I change state of other widget

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have two Widgets for my Login in a ListView. This allows me to navigate like that throuw sign up or sign in: [image: pic]

I want to change the Icon direction of both widgets, when I press one Button. I tried this with a Global Variable and a setState, but i guess this is a very bad practise :D Also it didnt worked out like I wish: Only the Icon I clicked on, change the direction, the other one dont update its state :(

I read something from a StreamBuilder, but have no idea how to implement it!

Here is one of my setStates:

```
 IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (showLogin) {
                                      controllerV.nextPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                                      setState((){
                                        showLogin = false;
                                      });


                                    } else {
                                      controllerV.previousPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700), curve: Curves.easeIn);

                                      setState((){
                                        showLogin = true;
                                      });
icon: showLogin? const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward) : const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward)),
```

I also provide my ListView, maybe it helps you to understand what my code do:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
  behavior: MyBehavior(),
  child: ListView(
      controller: controllerV,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: isKeyboardVisible? const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(): const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

      children:   const [
        LoginForm(),
        RegisterForm(),


      ]),
),
```

Comment: In general, one widget wanting to change the state of another widget is misdesign.

Comment: But there is no other way to design something like that. I could put both Widgets together, but then i have no ScrollViewController to scroll throuw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try any state manager it's a pretty bad practice to change any other widget state by one widget. I'll recommend you to learn about [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) but it's not beginner friendly you can start with the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or [Getx](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

Comment: I realised it with a simple cubit, I have already used Bloc/cubit before, but I m not a pro in that.  :D

Comment: If you know bloc it's humble advice to stick with it so you can explore more career opportunities. . Happy coding!